# Зачем в синтаксисе Delphi предусмотрена возможность присвоения значения в собственную функцию?

Tags: delphi

```
 function Func(X:integer):integer;
begin
   Result:=0;
   Func:= X;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Изначально в языке Pascal не было предопределённой переменной `Result`, и результат работы функции было необходимо присваивать самой функции.

Компилятор Borland Delphi имеет полную обратную совместимость с их же компилятором Borland Pascal, и даже имеет с ним общую нумерацию версий. Delphi v1 содержит компилятор версии 8.

Предопределённая переменная `Result` была добавлена уже в Delphi, но старый вариант оставлен для совместимости.